# Typedef struct question

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Why would I want to do this?

```
typedef struct Frame_s
{
int x;
int y;
int z;
} Frame_t;
```

Also if I want to create an object what do I use Frame_s or Frame_t?

Comment: You should probably avoid using the '_t' suffix for your own types as POSIX based systems reserve it for their own implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use `Frame_t`.

With `typedef` you are saying that `Frame_t` and `struct Frame_s` are **the exact same type**.

So these are equivalent sentences:

```
// 1
Frame_t f;

// 2
struct Frame_s f;
```

I would use:

```
typedef struct
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
} Frame_t;
```

And always declare my vars like this:

```
Frame_t f1, f2, f3;
```

Confusion usually comes from places where you use that sentence in a **C++** piece of code. If you use **C++** with that `typedef` you can use either:

```
// 1
Frame_t f;

// 2
Frame_s f;
```

But if you use a plain **C** compiler, then `//2` is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Either you use `struct Frame_s`, or you use `Frame_t`.

Usually you do such a typedef so that you can use the typedefed name, `Frame_t`, and don't have to write `struct` whenever you refer to the type.

Aside from `Frame_t` being shorter than `struct Frame_s` there is no real difference.

Answer (score 1):

Another aspect of `typedef` that has not yet been mentioned in the other replies is that it reserves the identifier and thus may avoid confusion. If you do a forward declaration like that

```
typedef struct Frame Frame;
```

you would avoid that some code that may use the same name `Frame` e.g a variable or function.

One very bad traditional example that comes in mind for this is *"sys/stat.h"* in POSIX: it defines a `struct stat` and a function `stat`:

```
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare a value of the struct, you could use either `struct Frame_s foo` or `Frame_t foo` (the latter is more normal, since that's the whole point of typedefing). My guess is that `Frame_s` is meant to indicate the struct type itself, while `Frame_t` is the plain type that's normally used for Frame values.

Comment: If the struct contains a pointer to itself, it needs to have a `struct Frame_s` name.  That struct could have a member `struct Frame_s * pointer;`, but not `Frame_t * pointer;`.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is used as a short form. So when a function which returns a structure of this type, normally you write -

`struct Frame_s *function_name()`

The code start to get obfuscated. Function definitions become long etc. With this `typedef` you get -

`Frame_t *function_name()`

Clean code! Makes a big difference in maintenance...

Answer (score 0):

So these two declarations are equivalent:

```
struct Frame_s f;
Frame_t f;
```

In fact, you could now leave `Frame_s` out of the declaration as it isn't needed.

```
typedef struct
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
} Frame_t;
```